# CSS line-height alignment issues

Tags: html, css

I am designing a website, with a quote on every page. I am applying CSS to this quote to make it look the best it can and stand out. However I am having a couple of issues.

```css
.quote {
  font-size: 18pt;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0.25;
}

.speech_mark_large {
  color: #203D69;
  font-size: 120px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <span class="speech_mark_large">&ldquo;</span> Leading the way with innovative design of corrugated Point of Sale displays and packaging offering bespoke design to fulfill your brief.
  <span class="speech_mark_large">&rdquo;</span>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/446dJ/).

I want the two lines of the quote to be closer together, but when I apply a line height, to solve this, it pushes the speech marks up into the previous line. How do I solve this?

Comment: Posting a JSFiddle is great, but please also post the code here, so in case the JSFiddle ever goes away, this question is still useful on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the `line-height` on the complete `.quote` element. Next you set `vertical-align` to `top` for the inner `.speech_mark_large` element. By changing the `line-height` of the `.quote` element you can tune the line spacing to what you think looks the best.

EDIT: I have added `top` and `position` to `.speech_mark_large` so you can change the vertical position of the quotes.

**CSS**

```
.quote {
    font-size:18pt;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.speech_mark_large {
    color:#203D69;
    font-size:50pt;
    vertical-align: top;
    top: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

See this updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxMYv/)

Comment: doesnt work if you go below the line-height:40px; so not really a feasible solution

Comment: I have updated my answer (and JSFiddle) to allow line-heights of less then 40px

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.speech_mark_large {
color:#203D69;
font-size:50pt;
line-height: 35px;
vertical-align:text-top;
}​
```

line height will make them take up less space from the inline text height (which in-turn makes them float over your other text).
The vertical-align will fix this by telling the quotes to align themselves to the text's bottom, rather than normally.